# Outlook Dialog in Add-ins use without deactivation of Pop-Up Block on Browser

Tags: javascript, outlook-web-addins

Actually, we're passing the Microsoft check for publishing our add-in. 
In MS-validation report, it's specified that any Pop-up windows that are triggered by user interaction must not be blocked by the browser Pop-up blocker when the Pop-up blocker is set to default value. 
Actually, the default value in browsers is set to "deactivated" for Pop-ups usage.

[MS-Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr7Q0.png)

We are using the Microsoft Office Outlook dialogs (Pop-ups) in our add-in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). They are specially dedicate for Add-ins, but this dialogs can only work when the Pop-up are activated.

How can we use this dialog and respect the MS-Report Pop-up Blocker too? 
Is there any solution to use this MS dialogs with deactivated Pop-ups?

Inform the user that he needs to activate the Pop-up to use the Add-in.

Here a code example using MS Dialogs:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("${hosting.server}${contextRoot}/app/ressource", {
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                promptBeforeOpen: false
            }, readMailAction.dialogCallback
        );
```

We tried to use promptBeforeOpen variable, but this variable only allows to hide the autorisation dialog of MS (Autorize open of a new Dialog to read the message), the pop-up blocker message is still there. See attached pictures. [Autorization Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLbe7.png) [Pop-Up Blocker dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7km3.png)

Comment: Can you please provide code sample of how you are using displayDialogAsync API? Are you using promptBeforeOpen option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialogoptions?view=office-js.

Comment: The topic has been edited with code sample and promptBeforeOpen variable use. The Pop-up blocker dialog is still shown, with this variable too. This variable allows us to hide the autorization dialog of MS, but not the Pop-up blocker Dialog of the Browser. (See attached pictures). How can we use the Office.context.ui dialog without Pop-ups or just not show this Pop-up blocked dialog ?

Comment: If the promptBeforeOpen is set to true then the framework displays a pop-up to trigger the navigation and avoid the browser's pop-up blocker. For details refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialogoptions?view=office-js

Comment: promptBeforeOpen option in UI Dialog does not avoid Poper Blocker. With both values, true or false, the pop-up blocker is shown, the only difference is that the Authorization Dialog (see picture above Authorization Dialog) is not shown anymore. Our question, is how to avoir Pop Up Blocker Dialog.

Comment: We are not able to repro this issue. Can you please share Stripped down version of add-in code?